# Init object with asynchronously downloaded data

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, asynchronous, initialization

I have an object that needs to be initialised with data from network and doesn't really make sense without the downloaded data. But it seems to me that doing an asynchronous network call in its `init` method is not a good idea because the object will not be ready to user right away and it might cause confusion. Should I only use a basic `init` method that will `alloc init` all its properties to create an empty object, and have other (non-`init`) methods  populate the data from the network which will be called explicitly by other objects (such as the view controller using this object)? What would be a good way to approach this?

Comment: Why not downloading your data, storing it temporary in a variable until you init your object with its value?

Comment: What is the object used for? What is the data? Does it make sense / can you download in advance? Is a placeholder object useful while the data is downloaded? Should a download be started and then the object as a whole is returned asynchronously?

Comment: It's a "User" class which has and can add/remove friends. The friend list is stored at the backend, so the `_friends` property has to be populated from the network. I want to encapsulate all my backend logic in the class so the view controller won't bother with it. At the moment I have an `init` method that `alloc init`s the properties, `addFriend` and `removeFriend` methods, and a `getFriendsFromBackendWithCompletionHandler` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution comes from having the right order of code running:

1) Go to network and fetch data (show the user acivity indicator in this time)

2) Server return response -> fetch the response into your object

3) Show the data or use it